# % wordcount in SPARK STREAMING (PYTHON)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, word-count

In the next example I´m receiving from Kafka a sequence words:

```
('cat')
('dog')
('rat')
('dog')
```

My objetive is calculate the % historic of each word. I will have two RDDs, one with the historic wordcount and another with the total of all words:

```
values = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})


def updatefunc (new_value, last_value):
    if last_value is None:
        last_value = 0
    return sum(new_value, last_value)


words=values.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)

historic= words.updateStateByKey(updatefunc).\
    transform(lambda  rdd: rdd.sortBy(lambda (x,v): x))

totalNo = words.\
    map(lambda x: x[1]).reduce(lambda a,b:a+b).map(lambda x: (('totalsum',x))).updateStateByKey(updatefunc).map(lambda x:x[1])
```

Now I'm trying to divide: ((historic value of each key)/totalNo)*100 to have the percentages of each word:

```
solution=historic.map(lambda x: x[0],x[1]*100/totalNo)
```

But I get the error:

```
 It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transforamtion. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063
```

How can I fix the value of `totalNO` to use it to operate in another RDDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this way can work as well:

```
words = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topics=['test'], kafkaParams={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})\
    .map(lambda x: x[1]).flatMap(lambda x: list(x))

historic = words.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).updateStateByKey(lambda x, y: sum(x) + (y or 0))

def func(rdd):
    if not rdd.isEmpty():
        totalNo = rdd.map(lambda x: x[1]).reduce(add)
        rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1] / totalNo))
    return rdd

solution = historic.transform(func)

solution.pprint()
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I suppose that rddQueue1 in your code is = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {brokers...}). I´m running 1.6 version so I will try in a few minuts an let you know. Thanks for this!

Comment: Indeed, I try with:" def func(a,b): return a.cartesian(b)
solution= historic.transformWith(func(historic,totalNo))" And I get the error:"AttributeError: 'TransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'cartesian'".

Comment: I think the solution is to make a clone of historic rdd and share the state with updatefunction of totalNo. And the join historic rdd and historic clone, and divide with reducebyKey(lambda a,b: a*100/b). But I don know how to share he state using updatestatbykey

Comment: @epic_last_song following your trying, it should be "def func(a, b): return a.cartesian(b) # solution = historic.transformWith(func, totalNo)" .

Comment: I get ('cat',0),('dog',0),('rat',0) all the time. Also I´m trying spliting historic in 2, in one have key-value and in the other have key-total and then join both rdds and reducebykey(lambda a,b:a/b) but is not dividing also. We are very close!

Comment: I´ve got it! I use your solution but there was pending cast to float both numbers in the division:                                                                                     def func(rdd):
    if not rdd.isEmpty():
        totalNo = rdd.map(lambda x: x[1]).reduce(add)
        rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], float(x[1]) / float(totalNo)))
    return rdd